# Building a set of tasks with asyncio, but total time takes longer than longest task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the following code, why does it take 10(0+1+2+3+4) seconds to finish, instead of 4 seconds, when I'm using asyncio?

```
import asyncio,time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"what = {what}, at {time.strftime('%X')}")


background_tasks = set()

async def main():
    for i in range(5):
        task = asyncio.create_task(say_after(delay=i,what=i))
        
        # Add task to the set. This creates a strong reference.
        background_tasks.add(task)
        
        await task
        
        # To prevent keeping references to finished tasks forever,
        # make each task remove its own reference from the set after
        # completion:
        task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard) # discard is a set method.
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The result is in the picture.

[image]

Edit:
I'm following [this official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to keep the `background_tasks` set if you are going to discard it after all tasks are done. Instead, I would use `asyncio.gather`

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[
        say_after(delay=i, what=i) for i in range(5)
    ])
```

In this case, you are not holding additional variables and awaiting all tasks at once. The final code should look like

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"what = {what}, at {time.strftime('%X')}")


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[
        say_after(delay=i, what=i) for i in range(5)
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

##### *Result*

```py
# what = 0, at 09:19:35
# what = 1, at 09:19:36
# what = 2, at 09:19:37
# what = 3, at 09:19:38
# what = 4, at 09:19:39
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the official documentation, whose link I've just added, they states that we should use that list to create a strong reference and prevent our tasks to be garbage collected...

My question is more about why my code doesn't work... According to the official documentation, it should work, no?

Comment: Well..., earlier, you did not mention that you are trying to execute a code from official docs, so I observed it as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Execute tasks outside the loop

```
import asyncio,time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"what = {what}, at {time.strftime('%X')}")


background_tasks = set()

async def main():
    for i in range(5):
        task = asyncio.create_task(say_after(delay=i,what=i))
        
        # Add task to the set. This creates a strong reference.
        background_tasks.add(task)
        
    await task
    
    # To prevent keeping references to finished tasks forever,
    # make each task remove its own reference from the set after
    # completion:
    task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard) # discard is a set method.
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... but why does it work? aren't we just running the last task this way?

Comment: Previously you were executing task right after you added it - and after execution main thread was waiting for the function to end. You can check it by printing **background_tasks** in the code from your question. When you do it outside of the loop the **backgournd_tasks** variable consists of all four tasks.

Comment: You are awaiting the last task only. Better to gather the set.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem with my code is that I was awaiting every task before having created all of them.
I should have created all the tasks first, and only then awaited all of them.

Here's how we can do this:

```
import asyncio,time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"what = {what}, at {time.strftime('%X')}")


background_tasks = set()

async def main():
    for i in range(5):
        task = asyncio.create_task(say_after(delay=i,what=i))
        
        # Add task to the set. This creates a strong reference.
        background_tasks.add(task)
        # To prevent keeping references to finished tasks forever,
        # make each task remove its own reference from the set after
        # completion:
        task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard) # discard is a set method.

    while len(background_tasks)!=0:
        await task
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

[image]